# Apple vs. VPN for security and tracking

Tags: wifi, security, vpn, privacy

I use ExpressVPN full-time on all devices.  Is there any added security or tracking benefit to adding any of Apple's IP address features, such as "Private Wi-Fi address" or "Limit IP Address Tracking" or anything else?  Can you point me to a discussion of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Private Wi-Fi Address is not related to your VPN, it randomized the hardware identifiers the Wi-Fi router sees (MAC Address). You can keep this on.

Limit IP Address Tracking is part of iCloud Private Relay. iCloud Private Relay disables when you have any VPN enabled.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I assume Apple substitutes ones of their so-far-unused MAC addresses in their reserved range. Is my originating MAC address obfuscated by a VPN?

Comment: No your VPN onky Protects network traffic not your connection itself

Answer (score 0):

It has “always” been my understanding that a VPN (or even a pseudo-vpn, like a DNS configuration) will not work along side Apple’s Private Relay, so I usually rely on my other services (aka AdGuard) to protect me… and I have seen documentation to that end, but this is an “off the tips of my fingers” answer…